# Execute a bash script only one time

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, daemon

Is there a way to make a bash script run only when the first terminal in the session is open?

Obviously sourcing it in the `~/.bashrc` file doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` may be what you're looking for with caveats.  (Such as terminal in mac calls bash_profile every time it's opened) . http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: Duplicate question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384574/execute-a-bash-script-only-one-time

Answer (score 2):

You could use `~/.profile`, which is executed when `bash` is started as a [login shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` may well be the answer (on a systemd system, if you can be sure that bash is used):

```
if ! [ -f /run/user/$UID/runonce_myscript ]; then
    touch /run/user/$UID/runonce_myscript
    /path/to/myscript
fi
```